# Getting status code 404 even though page exists

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, http-status-code-404

I have tried web scraping this particular link with java and python, but i keep getting a 404 status code even though it exists.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
from collections import defaultdict

url = 'https://www.slacker.com/station/pop-remix'

def main():
    page = requests.get(url)
    print(page.status_code)
    print()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: FWIW, I get `200` when I run your program.

Comment: Things I'd check in order. (1) Is this exactly the code you're running? (2) Are you running it from the same machine as your browser, or on some cloud server on a different network/geolocation/etc.? (3) Any chance that you triggered some "illegal scraping" detection and the server is now returning errors to all requests from your IP for a while?

Comment: I also got a 404 status. But it seems to actually be scraping the web page. ie page.content *does* contain the content of the page. It seems strange to me that it would be possible to scrape a page which was not found...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be some error on the server, but which does not fit into what we usually think of when we see a 404 (ie page wasn't found at all). I also received the 404 response when running your code. But when I called:

```
page.content
```

afterwards, it **did** dump the contents of the page. So I went to the link in my browser, and opened developer tools. In the console, I can see the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

even though the page is rendered in the browser... My guess is that the request is not fully satisfied (one part of the page is failing to load) and the server therefore decides to issue a 404 status, despite being able to give you plenty of other data.